# How to properly manage the order data is received and DOM updated in React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-apollo, react-context

I am using React Hooks and I want to use useMemo to trigger rerenders if and only if certain data changes.

i am also using apollo and I have a useQuery graphql query that I want to refresh under certain circumstances. The problem is, I'm getting some odd behaviour - sometimes the data just doesn't load. Also sometimes the context is not ready and no variables are passed to the useQuery.

My useMemo hook seems like it's repeating code, but getting rid of any of these if statements breaks the page.

Here is my functional component:

```
function Accounts(props) {
  const userContext = useContext(UserContext)
  const accountContext = useContext(AccountContext)

  const parentAccountID = userContext.userState.accountId
  const [parentAccountIDs, setParentAccountIDs] = useState(null)
  const [vars, setVars] = useState({
    parentIds: parentAccountIDs,
    offset: accountContext.accountState.data.accountsOffset,
    limit: accountContext.accountState.data.accountsLimit
  });

  const { 
    loading: loadingAccountUsers, 
    error: errorAccountUsers, 
    data: dataAccountUsers
  } = useQuery(GET_ACCOUNT_USERS, {
      variables: {
        accountId: parentAccountID
      }
  })

  const { 
    loading: loadingAccounts, 
    error: errorAccounts, 
    data: dataAccounts,
    refetch: refetchAccounts
  } = useQuery(GET_ACCOUNTS, {
      variables: {vars}
  })

  const { 
    loading: loadingAccountsTotal, 
    error: errorAccountsTotal, 
    data: dataAccountsTotal,
    refetch: refetchAccountsTotal
  } = useQuery(TOTAL_ACCOUNTS, {
      variables: {vars}
  })

  const setParentIDsHandler = (id) => {
    setParentAccountIDs(String(id))
  }

  const setOffset = (offset, limit) => {
    console.log("SET OFFSET", offset, limit)
    accountContext.accountDispatch({
      type: SET_ACCOUNTS_OFFSET, 
      payload: {
        offset: offset,
        limit: limit
      }
    })
    setVars({
      parentIds: parentAccountIDs,
      offset: accountContext.accountState.data.accountsOffset,
      limit: accountContext.accountState.data.accountsLimit
    })
  }

  useMemo(() => {
    if (dataAccountsTotal) {
      accountContext.accountDispatch({type: SET_ACCOUNTS_TOTAL, payload: dataAccountsTotal})
      console.log("TOTAL ACCOUNTS", accountContext.accountState.data.accountsTotal)
    }
    if (dataAccounts && dataAccountUsers && vars) {
      refetchAccounts(vars)
      accountContext.accountDispatch({type: GET_PARENT_ACCOUNT, payload: dataAccountUsers})
      accountContext.accountDispatch({type: SET_ACCOUNTS, payload: dataAccounts})
      setParentIDsHandler(dataAccountUsers.accountUsers[0].account.id)
    }
  }, [
    dataAccounts,
    dataAccountsTotal,
    dataAccountUsers,
    errorAccounts,
    loadingAccounts,
    parentAccountIDs,
    vars
  ])

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {
        accountContext.accountState.data.accounts && 
        !loadingAccountUsers &&
        !errorAccountUsers &&
        !loadingAccounts &&
        !errorAccounts &&
        parentAccountIDs &&
        accountContext.accountState.data.accountUsers 
        ? <AccountsGrid setOffset={setOffset}/> : <SpinnerLoader />}
    </Fragment>
  )
}
export default Accounts
```

When my handler function is called, sometimes the data being passed to the AccountsGrid component gets out of sync with the data from the server. How can I force React to wait for the data and only show it when it's available?

Comment: It looks like you're storing state both in the account context and the `vars` state value. This might be redundant; is there any reason to store this information twice? Your component should already be re-rendering if/when the context changes.

Comment: Note also that [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) is meant for creating values when dependent data changes. It's not for executing side effects like changing state or fetching data. For that you want [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). Check out the docs for both.

Comment: That does help the situation!

Comment: I also need useEffect to detect changes to the context caused by child components - is this possible?

Comment: Besides normal re-rendering (receipt of new props), the component will re-render when any state or context changes. If that's all you mean by 'detect', you get it for free. If you want to run some code when the context changes, useEffect is the way.
Keep in mind that React uses the dependency array you pass the hook to check for *reference* equality, not *value* equality. So if you provide the entire context object as a dependency, the effect will re-run if the object is not the precise object that was given last time, even if all the values within it look the same.

Comment: I'm still struggling with getting the child component to rerender. UseEffect 'detects' the change in the context, but the component stays the same

Comment: It's ok - the solution was removing useMemo for useEffect in the child component and not setting an initial state but fully relying on useContext. Anyone wants the credit post an answer and will accept